# List Category Plugin - Changing the links

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

Using the list category posts plugin I'm trying to work out how to include a title for the link

In my main theme the links are styles as follows:

```
<a title="Article - Post title" rel="bookmark" href="http://mysite/mypage/">Post title</a>
```

I want to do that using the category list plugin too, can that be done using the shortcode tags or would I need to put together a template?

Comment: This is finally going in (at least a first version) on release 0.24. I'll further work on it :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I should include this as an option on the plugin. Right now the code looks like this:

```
$info = '<a href="' . get_permalink($single->ID).'" >' . $single->post_title . '</a>';
```

So this generates a simple link:

```
<a href="yourpost.html">Post Title</a>
```

I'll see what I can do on a next version to make this customizable, but in the meantime you can go to line 164 on /include/CatListDisplayer.php and change that line into something like this:

```
$info = '<a href="' . get_permalink($single->ID).'" rel="bookmark" title='. $single->post_title . '>' . $single->post_title . '</a>';
```